# How to authenticate user with mobile app using Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, in-app-purchase

I want to build an app which will have in-app purchases.

So I have the following problem:

Users should be able to use my app on one device, and if they buy any in-app purchases using their account, they should have access to these features if they use the same app on another device with the same account. (account will probably be an email address/username).

How is this usually handled?

Or are users expected to pay for the same feature on different devices?
Or do I have to implement my own in-app purchase system?

Comment: I plan on developing my app using Apache Cordova for both iOS and Android, so the solution should ideally cover both platforms. This is also what makes my problem extra tricky. If a user has the app on ios and android i would ideally like their in-app purchases and profile synced on both devices.

Comment: yes, with cordova all you have to do is to sync data, thats it. check `firebase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the purchase info of the users along with their IDs, whether it is an email address or Game Center id, etc. Once you store this information, you can enable/disable features on any device based on purchase information you stored before. You don't have to do anything else related to Google Play Store or Apple iTunes.

I simply store the product id I sell and the ID of the users on my database. So they can use their purchases anywhere as long as they use the same credentials.

Comment: This makes sense, but it means i have to do some tracking of users and what they've purchases myself. Thought app stores could offer more help here.

Comment: If you are not going to track your users, this means you'll be dependent of the platform you run on (iOS or Android) which also means you need to implement restoring purchase process of the platform you run your app on. This also means your users lose the ability to purchase something on iOS and use it on Android or vice versa. My recommendation also support cross platform purchases.